# Как в один объект засунуть ключи и их значения

Tags: javascript, json, объекты, table

Необходимо, для того чтобы данные из таблицы вывести в формат json создать объекты и их запушить в массив. Не могу допереть как сделать объекты, вот код, в конце скрипта вся проблема:

```js
var block = document.getElementById('table');

var data = {
  persons: [{
      id: "1",
      name: "Ivan",
      age: 25,
      friends: 5

    },
    {
      id: "2",
      name: "Maria",
      age: 23,
      friends: 10
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      name: "Alex",
      age: 47,
      friends: 3,
    },
    {
      id: "4",
      name: "James",
      age: 34,
      friends: 12,
    }
  ]
};

var ttHead = document.createElement('thead');
var rowHead = document.createElement('tr');
var appearencies = {};
for (var n = 0; n < data.persons.length; n++) {
  for (var key in data.persons[n]) {
    appearencies[key] = key;
  }
}
for (key in appearencies) {
  var elHead = document.createElement('th');
  elHead.innerHTML = key;
  rowHead.appendChild(elHead);
  ttHead.appendChild(rowHead);
  block.appendChild(ttHead);

}


for (var i = 0; i < data.persons.length; i++) {
  var row = document.createElement('tr');
  for (var key in data.persons[i]) {
    var el = document.createElement('td');
    el.classList.add(key + 'Class');
    el.innerHTML = data.persons[i][key];
    row.appendChild(el);
  }
  block.appendChild(row);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("td").click(function() {
    if (this.firstChild.nodeType == 3) {
      $(this)[0].innerHTML = '<input type="text">';
    }
  });
});




var dataObj = {};
var dataArr = [];

var elBody = document.querySelectorAll('body > table > tr');
var elCell = document.querySelectorAll('body > table > tr > td');
var elTitle = document.querySelectorAll('body > table > thead > tr > th');
for (i = 0; i < elTitle.length; i++) {
  dataObj[elTitle[i].innerHTML] = '';
}
for (i = 0; i < elBody.length; i++) {
  var obj = new Object(dataObj);
  for (var j = 0; j < elBody[i].children.length; j++) {

  }
  console.log(obj);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table"></table>
<input id="go" type="button" name="go" value="SEND DATA">
```

Comment: Вам нужно создать JSON таблицы?

Comment: перенес твой код в сниппет: вроде все работает

Comment: @Grundy ему нужно заполнить `dataArr` - обратно из таблицы

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял Вам нужно серелизовать массив в json-строку. 
Это можно сделать методом [JSON.stringify(data)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

А если Вам нужно из готовой таблицы получить json, то [посмотрите это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927126/how-to-convert-the-following-table-to-json-with-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

```
...
el.innerHTML = data.persons[i][key];
el.setAttribute("keyName", key);
row.appendChild(el);


var obj = {};
for (var j = 0; j < elBody[i].children.length; j++) {
  obj[elBody[i].children[j].getAttribute("keyName")] = elBody[i].children[j].innerHTML;
}
dataArr.push(obj);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!